# Prove the set is Jordan- measurable and find the appropriate Jordan measure (volume) of the set V.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Prove the set is Jordan- measurable and find the appropriate Jordan measure (volume) of the set V.
$$V= \{ (x,y,z)|x^2+y^2\geq 1, x^2+y^2\leq2x, x^2+y^2+z^2 \geq 4, x+y+z\leq 8\} $$

I'm not sure if this question is within the curriculum that we have done thus far, i would appreciate any feedback on solving this.. Can it be solved without integrals ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This set is not bounded so is not Jordan-mesurable.

Comment: Doesnt x+y+z <= 8 make it bounded, sir? ;)

Comment: No, spot (3/2,0, -n) for every n >=3 belongs to this set

Comment: I agree. Very good answer.